# upload acceptable file type only php

Tags: php

I am doing a form that upload multiple images, how do I code such that files that are only 'jpg', 'png', 'gif' will be uploaded successfully and will skip those unacceptable files (eg. doc)? Currently my codes only allow upload if all files are accepted types and will prompt error even if there's only one file that is not acceptable file type

```
if ($source_type === NULL) {
    echo '<h3>Error</h3><br/>';
    echo 'Invalid file type<br/><br/>';
    echo '<input type="submit" style="color:#000000" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;" value="Back"><br/><br/>';
}
switch ($source_type) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromgif($source_file_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file_path);
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
        $source_gd_image = imagecreatefrompng($source_file_path);
        break;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_array()`.

```
$source_type_allowd = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
$source_type        = exif_imagetype($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name']);
$error              = !in_array($source_type, $source_type_allowd);// error
```

[exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) — Determine the type of an image.

Othe option:-

```
    $mime_type = $_FILES['file_upload']['type'];

    $allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
    if(!in_array($mime_type, $allowed)) {
      $msg = 'Only jpg, jpeg, and png files are allowed.';
    }else{
      // Upload process
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match()` function like this:

```
$filename = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
if(preg_match("/\.(gif|png|jpg)$/", $filename)){
   //file is gif/png/jpg
}
else{
   //invalid file format
   echo 'File should be gif|png|jpg';
}
```